# How to recover a file from a crashed emacs session

Tags: macos, emacs, crash

I'm running haskell-mode in emacs on OSX in iTerm2. Every so often emacs will freeze and I'll have to shutdown iTerm2. Since I often have ghci running inside of emacs (inside of iTerm2) it will crash my whole cpu causing an unexpected restart (gray screen of death). This time, the crash was so bad that it took the file with it (First time its done this). I have my files under source control in git but haven't committed in a while (200 lines). Now my file looks like this.

Am I out of luck or is there a way to restore a file in this state?
(Note: I tried the `M-x recover-file`) option.

**Update:** I do have some files in my `~/.emacs.d/auto-save-list`. When I try to recover them it says `"not current"`

```
;;; Automatically generated by `recentf' on Tue Mar  5 18:16:41 2013.

(setq recentf-list
      '(
        "/Users/Dave/Desktop/Jaskell/Parser/VMTranslator.hs"
        "/Users/Dave/Desktop/Jaskell/Parser/Decs.hs"
        "/Users/Dave/Desktop/Jaskell/Parser/SymbolTable.hs"
        "/Users/Dave/Desktop/Jaskell/Parser/Parser.hs"
        "/Users/Dave/.emacs.d/init.el"
        "/Users/Dave/Desktop/Jaskell/Parser/Printer.hs"
        "/Users/Dave/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0/snippets/c++-mode/io"
        "/Users/Dave/Desktop/Jaskell/11/Average/Main.jack"
        "/Users/Dave/.emacs.d/elpa/w32-browser-21.0/w32-browser-autoloads.el"
        ))

(setq recentf-filter-changer-current 'nil)


;; Local Variables:
;; coding: utf-8-emacs
;; End:
```

With a bunch of nulls at the end.

Comment: Have you tried running `cat` on your files in the autosave list? Can you at least access them that way?

Comment: When I run cat I get permission denied. λ wireless-207-154 auto-save-list → .saves-28401-wireless-199-16\~
.saves-28401-wireless-199-16~: line 1: /Users/Dave/Desktop/Jaskell/Parser/VMTranslator.hs: Permission Denied

Comment: that is really odd, try running it with root priveleges ....

Comment: found a link to address your "not current" issue: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/How+to+recover+Emacs+Autosave+files

Comment: Thanks, good link. When I try it I get "not current" for some reason. I chmodded 777 too this time just to be sure.

Comment: I think I'm screwed. Guess that's what I get for running emacs in a terminal ;)